# Menu block is not being displayed on the front page

Tags: blocks

I'm using the Menu Block content type to provide a list of the secondary level menu items down the left hand side of the website.

it works perfectly other than on the front page where I can't seem to make the menu Block display.

I'm using a Theme heavily based on Bartik (just with logos and colours changed), I can't find a specific front page template and have no idea what else to do.

I have changed the site configuration to use a basic page as the Home Page (but with this or the default home page it still doesn't work.

Anyone got any suggestions please?

Dave

Comment: How are your block visibility options ? Have you checked the 'Show on every page except listed' option ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I did check that, at the moment it is set to show on all pages except listed, with nothing in the list.

Comment: OK so that's definitely not the problem. Did you edit the front page template ? I would check that the region where the block belongs is correctly printed, for example by assigning another block to the same region and see what happens.

Comment: Can you test to see if you can get another type of block to show up on the home page? That would rule out it's a specific issue with Menu Block. Also, what if you switch to another theme temporarily, again for ruling things out / testing.

Comment: nice idea.The search bar appears as it should and if I move it from sidebar first then it disappears, I've also checked that the Menu exists etc.

Comment: So I have just discovered that if I set the menu block to start at the first item it will always be there.  It just doesn't seem to recognize the "home" menu item as being part of the item.

Comment: I think you have two separate problems here. The unrecognized menu item is one, probably related to Menu Block, the region not printed is another, related to your theme.

Comment: Have you tried the `page--front-tpl.php`?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a bug that I ran into myself and has been brought up here: http://drupal.org/node/1468420 (submenus of a parent menu item that links to the front page (`<front>`) do not show when viewing the site's front page). At the time of writing the bug has not been fixed, but there are 2 workarounds that might help you out:

1. Set the menu link with the `<front>` path to 'show as expanded'.
2. Do not use `<front>` as the menu link path, but instead use your actual front page path (same as in 'admin/config/system/site-information').

Comment: Nasty bug, this, but your solution worked perfectly for me. Thanks!

Comment: Set the menu link with the <front> path to 'show as expanded' is enough for me to make it working